# Dnspy can't compile MySql.Data

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, deobfuscation, dnspy

I have deobfuscated an executable file with de4dot and Dnspy. I can change and compile most of the classes but, I can't change and compile the ones that has MySql methods in it. It gives me an error: `type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found` .When I click on the `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` line, Dnspy leads me to an empty page. `Mysql.Data` is shown in the references folder but there is nothing inside it.

Comment: That is an external reference, not in the .exe itself but looks like MySql connector classes. You can look at it [at MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/N_MySql_Data_MySqlClient.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have put the mySql.data.dll in to the same folder and restarted the Dnspy. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an external reference, not in the .exe itself but looks like MySql connector classes.

I have downloaded MySql.Data.dll from nuget and put it into the same folder and restarted the Dnspy. It worked.